# Where can I find what the latest iptables version is?

Tags: iptables

I may be blind but I just can't see what the iptables latest version is.

I've checked [iptables homepage](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/index.html).

I've also searched the internet and nothing.

Comment: When you say "iptables" do you mean just the user space utilities? If so [you can just check out the downloads page](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/downloads.html).

Comment: You can check on the News page of the netfilter project - http://www.netfilter.org/news.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can read, latest version is 1.4.21 from Nov 22nd 2014. [Link](http://www.netfilter.org/news.html#2012-10-08c)

Answer (score 0):

iptable releases are here: https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/downloads.html

At time of writing, the latest is iptables-1.6.2, but it updates pretty often.